# Using sed to replace the last occurrence of character

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting

I'm trying to replace the last occurrence of a character within a multi line string variable.

I need to replace the last `|` with a `` ` ``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe through `rev`, replace the first occurrence, and then through `rev` again:

```
rev | sed -e 's/|/`/' | rev
```

Alternatively, in pure `sed`, you want to replace `|` *followed by anything not including `|`* with `` ` `` followed by the same sequence:

```
sed -e 's/|\([^|]*\)$/`\1/'
```

I'd argue that the first of those is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you. But these expressions replace the last instance on each line. I'd like to replace the very last occurrence within the variable.

Comment: If you have GNU sed (likely, as you're on Linux), you can set the line separator to be the NUL character, using `-z` or `--null-data`, so your entire input will be considered as a single line.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the fact that `.*` is greedy:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)|/\1`/'
```

Or use:

```
sed 's/|\([^|]*\)$/`\1/'
```

To match on `|` followed by something that doesn't contain `|` til the end of line as already shown by Toby, but that approach only works for single character replacements.

To replace it in a multiline string shell variable, with GNU `sed`, you can use the `-z` option which treats the input as NUL delimited instead of newline delimited:

```
var=$(printf %s "$var" | sed -z '...')
```

Another approach would be to do the substitution using standard parameter expansion operators:

```
case $var in
  (*'|'*) var=${var%'|'*}'`'${var##*'|'}
esac
```

Or with those `sed` commands translated to their shell equivalent:

In `ksh93`:

```
var=${var/@(*)'|'/\1'`'}
var=${var/%'|'*([^'|'])/'`'\1}
```

In `bash` (assuming the string doesn't contain byte sequences not forming valid characters in the current locale):

```
re='(.*)\|(.*)'
[[ $var =~ $re ]] && var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}'`'${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

In `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
var=${var/(#b)(*)'|'/$match[1]'`'}

var=${var/%(#b)'|'([^'|']#)/'`'$match[1]}
```

Comment: Thank you. But these expressions replace the last instance on each line. I'd like to replace the very last occurrence within the variable.

Comment: @Chris, I had missed that part of your requirement. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$str"
abc|def
ghi|jkl
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${str%\|*}"'`'"${str##*\|}"
abc|def
ghi`jkl
```

- `${str%\|*}` expands to the string with the last `|` and everything after it removed.
- `${str##*\|}` expands to the string with the last `|` and everything before it removed.

The combination of the above two parameter substitutions, with a `` ` `` in-between, gives the result string.

Comment: It's actually very nice. Without using sed or awk.

Answer (score 1):

Part of @Stéphane Chazelas' answer in a more "didactic" way...

```
sed -z 's/\(.*\)<YOUR_ESCAPED_TARGET>/\1<YOUR_ESCAPED_REPLACE>/'
```

Note the use of `-z` which allows both `<YOUR_ESCAPED_TARGET>` and `<YOUR_ESCAPED_REPLACE>` to have multiple lines.

**NOTE:** A more complete answer that explains how `<YOUR_ESCAPED_TARGET>` and `<YOUR_ESCAPED_REPLACE>` can be escaped can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73213919/3223785).

**Thanks!**